# Как исправить вылеты Drawer Activity на старых устройствах?

Tags: android, android-studio

Создал Drawer Activity в Android Studio, сам толком ничего не изменял, но есть она проблема на устройствах с Android ~4.0 из за этой активности вылетает всё приложение с такой ошибкой:

```
08-31 12:51:49.057 E/AndroidRuntime(4319): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-31 12:51:49.057 E/AndroidRuntime(4319): Process: ru.xxxx, PID: 4319
08-31 12:51:49.057 E/AndroidRuntime(4319): android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f070094
08-31 12:51:49.057 E/AndroidRuntime(4319):  at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1123)
08-31 12:51:49.057 E/AndroidRuntime(4319):  at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.loadDrawableFromDelegates(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:328)
08-31 12:51:49.057 E/AndroidRuntime(4319):  at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:193)
08-31 12:51:49.057 E/AndroidRuntime(4319):  at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:186)
08-31 12:51:49.057 E/AndroidRuntime(4319):  at android.support.v7.content.res.AppCompatResources.getDrawable(AppCompatResources.java:100)
08-31 12:51:49.057 E/AndroidRuntime(4319):  at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.getIcon(MenuItemImpl.java:491)
08-31 12:51:49.057 E/AndroidRuntime(4319):  at android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuItemView.initialize(NavigationMenuItemView.java:118)
08-31 12:51:49.057 E/AndroidRuntime(4319):  at android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuPresenter$NavigationMenuAdapter.onBindViewHolder(NavigationMenuPresenter.java:429)
08-31 12:51:49.057 E/AndroidRuntime(4319):  at android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuPresenter$NavigationMenuAdapter.onBindViewHolder(NavigationMenuPresenter.java:352)
08-31 12:51:49.057 E/AndroidRuntime(4319):  at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6673)
08-31 12:51:49.057 E/AndroidRuntime(4319):  at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.bindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6714)
08-31 12:51:49.057 E/AndroidRuntime(4319):  at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryBindViewHolderByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5647)
08-31 12:51:49.057 E/AndroidRuntime(4319):  at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5913)
08-31 12:51:49.057 E/AndroidRuntime(4319):  at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5752)
08-31 12:51:49.057 E/AndroidRuntime(4319):  at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5748)
08-31 12:51:49.057 E/AndroidRuntime(4319):  at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2232)
08-31 12:51:49.057 E/AndroidRuntime(4319):  at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1559)
08-31 12:51:49.057 E/AndroidRuntime(4319):  at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1519)
08-31 12:51:49.057 E/AndroidRuntime(4319):  at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:614)
08-31 12:51:49.057 E/AndroidRuntime(4319):  at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3812)
08-31 12:51:49.057 E/AndroidRuntime(4319):  at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:3529)
08-31 12:51:49.057 E/AndroidRuntime(4319):  at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:4082)
08-31 12:51:49.057 E/AndroidRuntime(4319):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
08-31 12:51:49.057 E/AndroidRuntime(4319):  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
08-31 12:51:49.057 E/AndroidRuntime(4319):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
08-31 12:51:49.057 E/AndroidRuntime(4319):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
08-31 12:51:49.057 E/AndroidRuntime(4319):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
08-31 12:51:49.057 E/AndroidRuntime(4319):  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
08-31 12:51:49.057 E/AndroidRuntime(4319):  at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onLayout(DrawerLayout.java:1195)
08-31 12:51:49.057 E/AndroidRuntime(4319):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
08-31 12:51:49.057 E/AndroidRuntime(4319):  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
08-31 12:51:49.057 E/AndroidRuntime(4319):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
08-31 12:51:49.057 E/AndroidRuntime(4319):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
08-31 12:51:49.057 E/AndroidRuntime(4319):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
08-31 12:51:49.057 E/AndroidRuntime(4319):  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
08-31 12:51:49.057 E/AndroidRuntime(4319):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1671)
08-31 12:51:49.057 E/AndroidRuntime(4319):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1525)
08-31 12:51:49.057 E/AndroidRuntime(4319):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1434)
08-31 12:51:49.057 E/AndroidRuntime(4319):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
08-31 12:51:49.057 E/AndroidRuntime(4319):  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
08-31 12:51:49.057 E/AndroidRuntime(4319):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
08-31 12:51:49.057 E/AndroidRuntime(4319):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
08-31 12:51:49.057 E/AndroidRuntime(4319):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
08-31 12:51:49.057 E/AndroidRuntime(4319):  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
08-31 12:51:49.057 E/AndroidRuntime(4319):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1671)
08-31 12:51:49.057 E/AndroidRuntime(4319):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1525)
08-31 12:51:49.057 E/AndroidRuntime(4319):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1434)
08-31 12:51:49.057 E/AndroidRuntime(4319):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
08-31 12:51:49.057 E/AndroidRuntime(4319):  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
08-31 12:51:49.057 E/AndroidRuntime(4319):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
08-31 12:51:49.057 E/AndroidRuntime(4319):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
08-31 12:51:49.057 E/AndroidRuntime(4319):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
08-31 12:51:49.057 E/AndroidRuntime(4319):  at android.view.ViewGroup.
08-31 12:51:49.057 W/ActivityManager(471):   Force finishing activity ru.xxxxx/.НазваниеАктивити
08-31 12:51:49.067 W/WindowManager(471): updateFocusedWindowLocked, focusedAppToken is null.
08-31 12:51:49.567 W/ActivityManager(471): Activity pause timeout for ActivityRecord{4a7c0640 u0 ru.alexandercold.a3rd/.НазваниеАктивити t28 f}
```

Можно ли её как то решить?

Comment: Версия `com.android.support:appcompat` какая?

Comment: Лог ошибки можно и нужно добавить прямо в вопрос.

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете проверить свой R. файл на `Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f070094.` Он скажет вам, какой ресурс создает проблему.

Посмотрите на какой файл ругается и приложите к вопросу XML разметку с этим файлом